# Springboot Override Global Allowed Origins configuration from a Controller/Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, iframe, cors

I have an application with cors filter which only allows certain origins.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    @Value("${allowed.origins}")
    private String[] allowedOrigins;
    private String[] allowedMethods = {"GET","HEAD","OPTIONS","POST","PUT","DELETE"};

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(allowedMethods));
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(allowedOrigins));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

I also have a controller that needs calling from no origin (from an **iframe** that does not have any origin).

```
    @PostMapping("/start-payment")
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<?> startPayment(@RequestParam Double amount) {
        String jwt = cybersourcePaymentService.initiatePayment(amount);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(jwt);
    }
```

Is there a way to allow only this method to be called from origin that is not mentioned in WebConfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, you can do this by adding `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` annotation on top of a specific method. I have tested this and it is working fine.

```
    @PostMapping("/start-payment")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    public ResponseEntity<?> startPayment(@RequestParam Double amount) {
        String jwt = cybersourcePaymentService.initiatePayment(amount);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(jwt);
    }
```

**Note:** *If there is a global CORS configuration and method level CORS configuration is available in any project then method level CORS takes preference.*